# React Redux - localStorage cart empty after refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage

After every refresh my cart gets empty. How can i make it persist a refresh and just empty after browser restart?

I added fully code + getItem for the initialState.
But i don't know how to check for the initialState and if there is no initialstate use setItem...

```
const savedCartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) || [];

const initialState = {
  cartItems: savedCartItems || [], // Cart initially contains no items unless retrieved in localStorage
};

export const addToCart =
  (dish, quantity, variant, toppings, removeIng, sumOfToppings) =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    var cartItem = {
      name: dish.name,
      _id: dish._id,
      image: dish.image,
      variant: variant,
      quantity: Number(quantity),
      toppings: toppings,
      removeIng: removeIng,
      prices: dish.prices,
      sumOfToppings: sumOfToppings,
      price: (parseFloat(variant) + sumOfToppings) * quantity,
    };
    if (cartItem.quantity > 20) {
      alert('Du kannst dieses Gericht maximal 20 mal hinzufügen.');
    } else {
      if (cartItem.quantity < 1) {
        dispatch({
          type: 'DELETE_FROM_CART',
          payload: dish,
        });
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
          payload: cartItem,
        });
      }
    }

    const cartItems = getState().cartReducer.cartItems;
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
  };

export const deleteFromCart = (dish) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'DELETE_FROM_CART',
    payload: dish,
  });
  const cartItems = getState().cartReducer.cartItems;
  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
};
```

Comment: You call `setItem()` here but do you ever call `getItem()`? Likely when you create the default state, you could check for a saved cart and use that if it exists.

Comment: No i dont have. I've not really much knowledge about localStorage... Can you show me how to implement getItem so i can test if your solution works for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to my store made it work. Thanks to everyone who helped me!

```
const cartItems = localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
  : [];

const initialState = {
  cartReducer: {
    cartItems: cartItems,
  },
};
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution 

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [mherzig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1795669/mherzig) you are persisting your state through your browser's `localStorage` but you are not getting that data back (at least not correctly).

If you want the quick answer:

1. Pull your persisted `cartItems` from `localStorage`:

`const savedCartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) || []`

2. Use that value in your initial Redux's state:

```
const initialState = {
  // Whatever state you might have
  //....

  cartItems: savedCartItems || [], // Cart initially contains no items unless retrieved in localStorage
}
```

To be sure that your state is correctly persisted, open your brower's devtools and head over to `Application` then `Local Storage`, if your data is there then you are sure that your state is persisted.

In case it would help — [here's an example I had worked on with Redux Toolkit](https://github.com/YHADJRABIA/ecommerce/blob/main/src/redux/cartSlice.js)

Comment: Thank you, i think it's step in correct way. I updated my post with all code in my cartAction + initalState you wrote me. But Im not sure what to do next bcs i work with a setState in the addToCart and in your git repo i don't see that you work with setItem so im kinda confused how to make it run for my version.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I use `initialState` as a complex state with Redux. You seem to be doing the same with your `cartItem` object but for something else.

Are you using Redux Toolkit where actions and reducers are combined as one `slice` (with a separate store file) or the "old" Redux where everything comes separately?

Your cart reducer has to have a "global" state, dispatching actions change that state depending on the payload. Question is — where is your global state? It has to be initialised somewhere, that's where one should use `localStorage` on the relevant field

Comment: I've a store. I found solution btw. ill post it as answer